# 2018 MacBook Pro (w/ Touch Bar): Are all 4 thunderbolt/USB-C ports capable of supporting a monitor?

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt

I have a fairly new 2018 13" Macbook Pro w/ touchbar. Only the two USB-C ports which are closest to the corners seem to support an external monitor. Is this expected behavior?

To clarify, there are 4 total USB-C ports (2 on the left and 2 on the right). The two which work at the closest to the "esc" key and the fingerprint sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple's specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP775?locale=en_US) on this MacBook Pro all four ports support video:

```
 Charging and Expansion

 Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports with support for:

 Charging 
 DisplayPort 
 Thunderbolt (up to 40 Gbps) 
 USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)
```

If two of the ports are not supporting video you could look at the cabling (try another cable, etc.) and monitor compatibility (Thunderbolt 3?). Failing that take it to an Apple store and have them test it.